# Ошибка papyros.io (arch linux)

Tags: linux

Установил арч линукс, пытаюсь установить оболочку http://papyros.io/, делаю все по документации http://papyros.io/download/. на этапе `pacman -Syu` появляется ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

OS 32 bit

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что все очевидно

Comment: Почему все так любят текст вставлять в виде картинок? @justness, перевыложи в виде вставки кода.

Answer (score 2):

Все же очевидно.
Papyros - находится в alpha стадии разработки.
А http://dash.papyros.io/repos/ - не открывается даже через браузер. Получается, репозитории у ребят сломались. Мы тут ничего сделать не можем.